# Compiler behaviour when constructing virtual base class

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, constructor, virtual-inheritance

Consider this piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
  public:
    A(int s) { std::cout << "A(" << s << ")\n"; }
};

class B1 : virtual public A {
  public:
    B1(int s1, int s2)
        : A{s1} { std::cout << "B1(" << s1 << "," << s2 << ")\n"; }
};

class B2 : virtual public A {
  public:
    B2(int s1, int s2)
        : A{s1} { std::cout << "B2(" << s1 << "," << s2 << ")\n"; }
};

class C1 : public B1, public B2 {
  public:
    C1() : B1{1,2}, B2{3,4}, A{5} {}
};

class C2 : public B1, public B2 {
  public:
    C2() : B1(1,2), B2(3,4), A{5} {}
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Create c1:\n";
    C1 c1;

    std::cout << "\n";
    std::cout << "Create c2:\n";
    C2 c2;

}
```

Class A is a virtual base class of B1 and B2. Classes C1 and C2 are identical, except that C1 uses `{...}` and C2 uses `(...)` to construct B1 and B2.

Because of the virtual inheritance used here, class A should be constructed as part of the construction of C1 or C2.

If I compile this code with Microsoft VS2015, it produces this output when running:

```
Create c1:
A(5)
B1(1,2)
B2(3,4)

Create c2:
A(5)
B1(1,2)
B2(3,4)
```

which is exactly what I would expect.

But if I compile it with GCC (6.1.0) it produces this output:

```
Create c1:
A(5)
A(1)
B1(1,2)
A(3)
B2(3,4)

Create c2:
A(5)
B1(1,2)
B2(3,4)
```

Here, A's constructor is called three times when constructing c1, but only once when constructing c2.

Is this a bug in GCC or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: You may consider to add the regular C++ tag, to get a broader audience.

Comment: Okay, @Jonas, I replaced the c++11 tag with c++. (I cannot have more than 5 tags.)

Comment: Have you tried Clang as well? I'm 99% sure this is a bug.

Comment: Clang (3.8.0) behaves like MS VS2015.

Comment: It's a bug, and it seems to be fixed in trunk.

Comment: Yes, @bogdan, it must be a bug. Now, if you would change your comment into an answer, I will acknowledge it as the answer to my question.

Comment: To be honest, I'd feel bad if I got an accepted answer only for pasting your code into Wandbox :-). You already did all the work, basically, and did it well. One of the answers below at least adds a bit more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

Apparently, GCC does have a bug in this case. Compiling the code with GCC version 7.0.0 produces the correct behaviour with this output:

```
Create c1:
A(5)
B1(1,2)
B2(3,4)

Create c2:
A(5)
B1(1,2)
B2(3,4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure why is it so, but shouldn't A class be polymorphic (have at least one virtual function) to properly virtually inherit from it?!

Comment: Tried it with A polymorphic, with gcc  5.4.0, the same bug.

Comment: Interesting that sizeof(c1) and sizeof(c2) for gcc are the same and if a method is declared in A it can be called from c1 or c2 without ambiguity.

Comment: Virtual base classes are *usually* polymorphic, as abstract interface classes. But the property of being a base is a property inside a derived class; a type is only a virtual or non virtual base inside a derived class.

Answer (score 0):

The bug is much worse:

```
    #include <iostream>

    class A {
       public:
          A(int s) { std::cout << "A(" << s << ")\n"; ms = s; };
          int ms;
          virtual void dummy() {std::cout << "Aaaaaa!" << std::endl;};
          virtual ~A() {std::cout << "~A(" << ms << ")\n";};
    };

    class B1 : virtual public A {
        public:
           B1(int s1, int s2)
              : A{s1} { std::cout << "B1(" << s1 << "," << s2 << ")\n"; };
    };

    class B2 : virtual public A {
        public:
           B2(int s1, int s2)
              : A{s1} { std::cout << "B2(" << s1 << "," << s2 << ")\n"; };
    };

       class C1 : public B1, public B2 {
           public:
              C1() : B1{1,2}, B2{3,4}, A{5}  {};
       };

       class C2 : public B1, public B2 {
           public:
              C2() : B1(1,2), B2(3,4), A{5} {};
       };

      int main()
      {
         {
             std::cout << "Create c1:\n";
             C1 c1;
             std::cout << "Calling A's dummy on c1: " << std::endl;
             c1.dummy();
             std::cout << "Size of c1: " << sizeof(c1) << std::endl;
         }

         {
             std::cout << "\n";
             std::cout << "Create c2:\n";
             C2 c2;
             std::cout << "Calling A's dummy on c2: " << std::endl;
             c2.dummy();
             std::cout << "Size of c2: " <<sizeof(c2) << std::endl;
         }

     }
```

Compiled on GCC 5.4.0
Running this code produced the following output:

- Create c1:
- A(5)
- A(1)
- B1(1,2)
- A(3)
- B2(3,4)
- Calling A's dummy on c1:
- Aaaaaa!
- Size of c1: 32
- ~A(3)

---

- Create c2:
- A(5)
- B1(1,2)
- B2(3,4)
- Calling A's dummy on c2:
- Aaaaaa!
- Size of c2: 32
- ~A(5)

Comment: What new bug have you discovered here? Except for the bug I mentioned in the original post, your code behaves entirely as expected, as far as I can see.

Comment: The bug is the same, you are right. Just would like to point to A's destructor calls.